# something strange about radarchart function in fmsb package

Tags: r, radar-chart

I am using the  *radarchart* function in fmsb package to plot radar chart on my data, I found something strange, the point in the radar chart  is seemly not correspond to it's real value, below I give a example to illustrate it：

```
library(fmsb)

maxmin1 <- data.frame(
  total_score=c(10,1),
  ability=c(10,1),
  honesty=c(10,1),
  willing=c(10,1),
  background=c(10,1)
)


a1 <- data.frame(
  total_score=c(2),
  ability=c(4),
  honesty=c(6),
  willing=c(8),
  background=c(10)
)

dat <- rbind(maxmin1,a1)

radarchart(dat,axistype=1,seg=5,plty=1,vlcex=0.6)
```

[image]

**In this example, my total_score value is 2, but in radar chart this point is below 2. And the ability value is also below it's real value .
Why this happens? Is there something wrong in my code?
I would appreciate it if you could answer my question. Looking forward to your reply.**

Answer (score 0):

You have set up `1` as your minimum (`10` as maximum value). Hence, 2 is not 20% way between 1 and 10.

If you put 0 as your minimum, you will see that radar will match at 20%.